# How to set user locale on remembered login in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication, local

I am working on a `Symfony 2.8` based project. The webpage can be used in different languages and the selected language is stored in the `Session`. Using a `Locale Listener` class it is no problem to set the the correct locale when the user enters the page or logs in:

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'de') {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => array(array('onSecurityInteractiveLogin', 18)),                
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'onAuthenticationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) 
            return;

        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {            
            // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter    
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session            
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
        // ...get locale from user settings and it info to session...
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent $event) {
        // ...get locale from user settings and it info to session...
    }
}
```

This the same code as in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html) extended with login listeners. It works great when the user actively logs in. In this case both the `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` and the `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` are triggered (BTW: What is the difference between the two)?

However if the user is logged in and access a page, none of the two events is triggered.

This is a problem when the session is expired and the `remember_me` cookie is not. I came across when refreshing the page in the browser after I have not worked on that machine for a few days: The `remember_me` cookie was still active and thus the user was still logged in. However the page was refreshed in the default language and not in the user language, which is only possible when the session expired in the mean while...

I have not configured a session life time in the config file and the Symfony debug toolbar shows a session lifetime of 0. Of course I could extend the lifetime and make it longer than the lifetime of the remember_me option. However it would be a much cleaner solution to re-read the locale from the user settings every time the user is authenticated.

I assume that authentication is done on every single request. Either through the user credentials which are submitted by the login form (= interactive login) or by the information stored in the `remember_me` cookie. Is't that correct?

In this case I would expect, that an `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` event is triggered on every request. But this seems not to be the case.

**Long story short:**

How can I make sure, that the locale from the user settings is used as long the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience every time we make a request( if session based authentication) symfony checks if the request matches any active session ( using some cookie as session identifier or something similar). If so, then `onAuthenticationSuccess` is triggered, otherwhise you are redirected to login page. Once the login form is submitted and  if user credentials are valid you are authenticated and the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` is triggered.

So, `onAuthenticationSuccess` triggers if credentials valid  in every request, while `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` triggers on successful login submit only.
In any case after sucessfully authenticated you are forwarded to your target url throughout the kernel events, starting for the `onKernelRequest` event.

So, I think the problem could be that when sucessfull `onAuthenticationSuccess` happens you actually populate the user language into the session, but after that `onKernelRequest` is triggered and you override that info with this

```
$request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
```

If that is the problem, consider setting the language just in the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` event